# Specific X-Value labels for SSRS scatter plot

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, scatter-plot

I am trying to reproduce this graph

[image]

I am having issues setting the x-axis to be the values 1,8,30,50,100,150,200.
I also have no idea how I can get the secondary y-axis to have labels at the defined x-axis.

I took the SQL and created another column called CallOutPoints  which just did a simple IIF(X NOT IN (1,8,30,50,100,150,200) then NULL. I then added this but I still can't get the x-axis or y-axis intervals/labels to match what I am after.

My attempt you can see the blue markers which are my calloutpoints, I just want the x-axis to only show ticks at each non-null calloutpoints value and the secondary-y axis to have tickmarks at every non-null calloutpoint.

FRACTION = Red markers
CallOutPoints = Blue Markers

[image]

[image]